# Manage NuGet Packages not visible on menu

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Using Visual Studio 2012 Premium on Win 7 x64, I make a new project (an MVC 4 project). When right-clicking on the project, I see no 'Manage NuGet Packages' option. A packages folder exists in the solution directory, as does a package.config file in the project directory. When going to `Tools`, there is no `Manage NuGet Packages` option, either. When going to `Tools`->`Extensions and Updates...`, the `NuGet Package Manager` is installed and up to date.

Any idea why my project is unable to manage the NuGet packages for itself?

Here's a screenshot of the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution came in the form of wiping out all traces of the **NuGet Package Manager**, including all registry files. Because the registry files have weird names, searching for things like `NuGet.Core` as well as just about anything in the `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions` folder. After clearing those out, restarting the computer, reinstalling NuGet, and then restarting again seemed to clear up the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. The problem was next:
I've installed **NuGet Packager** instead of **NuGet Package Manager** (from Extensions and Updates). Once I've installed the last one, it appeared in the context menu. Maybe you faced the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that is not the case. It was the _NuGet Package Manager_ for sure.

Answer (score 5):

I had to uninstall the Nuget Package Manager from Extensions and Updates, and then reinstall it. After restarting Visual Studio, the missing menu entries appeared.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are something's you should check

- Make sure you are in debug mode
- Make sure your not running the debugger
- The 'NuGet Package Manager' is installed and not the 'NuGet
  Packager'
- Your project was created using the VS IDE - to check this, you can
  simply create a new solution in VS and see that you are still
  missing the 'Manage NuGet Packages' option in the menu.

Now if this issue still appears you can try taking the following steps:

1. Clean out your Extensions folder.
   Extensions folder can be found
   under the VS folder \Common7\IDE\Extensions. i.e. if vs2013 in 64
   bit, then C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
2. Uninstall the NuGet Package Manager from Extensions and Updates
3. Restart VS
4. Install the NuGet Package Manager from Extensions and Updates

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Because of reasons, It seems that Nuget Package Manager was not installed on my fresh Visual Studio Professionnal 2013 edition.
Installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your Extensions folder in [if vs2013 in 64 bit, then C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions]

Each extension has folder in here with manifest file extension.manifest, check these xml files - node "Name" and if found duplicate, remove duplicate folders, restart Visual Studio.

If there is same extension in different folder, VS is confused and will not load it...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the project was running. When stopped, the menu items appeared.